# Award bounty button missing in mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

I offered a bounty on a question, then wanted to award the bounty. Should be simple enough.  Except I'm using the mobile site, and the button to award the bounty is missing... I'm not blind, as if I switch to the desktop version the button's there again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *should* have worked all along but a bug in the razor view meant these just weren't being rendered correctly.  Normally I err on the side of keeping mobile as clean as possible, but since we allow you to *start* a bounty via mobile, it seems like a jerk move to not allow you to award it.

Starting with the next build you'll have bounty indicators and a working button to award just like the main site.