# iOS Mobile App is missing the award bounty button

Tags: feature-request, bounties, ios-app

[I've seen awhile back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106204/271905) that a bug was posted stating that there isn't an <kbd>Award Bounty</kbd> button in the mobile site.

However, this time, I've noticed that in the mobile app, there is a notification about bounties but there isn't a button to award it?

Is it a bug or intended feature?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243728/allow-adding-bounties-from-the-android-app (I'm afraid the answer is the same: too complicated to do, hence won't happen. That said, the android app is abandonded, so even actual bugs are not fixed these days.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's [iOS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243346/allow-adding-bounties-from-the-ios-app) actually. Come to think of it, this may be a duplicate (despite the contexts).

Comment: oops. Still, the problem is the API which doesn't support it behind the scenes, so my comments sticks. :)